# Vlookup across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Within one workbook, I have two spreadsheets.
Sheet A ("Master") looks like the following - it shows a main branch with it sub branches.

[image: Master]

Sheet B ("Query") looks like the following:

[image: Query]

The problem is that a lot of the branches in Col C of "Query" are sub branches which are only in Col D, E, F or G of "Master." What I want to do in Col A of "Query" is display the main branch of my sub branch in Col C.

I've tried something like this to test 2 columns, but it gives me back the main branch name and if it's a sub branch, only the number:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,Master!A:G,3,FALSE), VLOOKUP(B:B,Master!D:D,1,FALSE))
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to look up query(B) to match Master(D,E,F,G) and if so, return Master(C)?

Comment: Almost, except query(B) needs to match Master(A,D,E,F,G) and if so return Master (C)

Comment: Oh, yeah I see that now. This will be a very complex formula and may require you to re-organize the sheet. VBA would be more efficient. Since you tagged WS-Function, I'll let someone better at formulas than me tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an array formula solution. Select `A2` on the Query sheet and paste the following into the formula bar.

```
=INDEX(Master!$C$1:$C$9,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND("|"&B2&"|","|"&Master!$A$1:$A$9&"|"&Master!$D$1:$D$9&"|"&Master!$E$1:$E$9&"|"&Master!$F$1:$F$9&"|"&Master!$G$1:$G$9&"|")),-1,1)*ROW(Master!$A$1:$A$9)))
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter as an array formula. Then fill down the column.

*Explanation:*
This formula creates an array of the concatenated branch and sub-branch codes for each store on the Master sheet. The codes are separated by a character that does not occur in any of the codes (`|`). For example, the first entry in the array would be

```
|42981|0|0|21743|0|
```

The formula then searches for the code from Query sheet column B wrapped in the delimiter characters (e.g. `|26183|`). For any match, the row number of the match is stored in an array. For non-matches, `-1` is stored.

The `MAX` value of this array of row numbers and -1's is taken and passed to the `INDEX` function, which looks for that specific index in column C on the Master sheet. If `-1` is passed to the `INDEX` function, i.e., if no matching code was found, an error is returned.

Comment: Tried the formula and it created the {} for the array, but it returns #VALUE! Am i doing something wrong? http://postimg.org/image/763achcib/

Comment: @Lisa You need to update the ranges in the formula to match your data. As is, it's only looking down to row 9 on the Master sheet.

Comment: My mistake! Was overeager. Thank you, working perfectly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is easily expandable for additional sub columns:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(MainList,IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(SubTable=a2))<>1,NA(),SUMPRODUCT(ROW(SubTable)*(SubTable=a2))-ROW(SubTable)+1)),0,2)
```

MainList:  Named range of master branch IDs (A2:Axxx)

SubTable:  Named range of sub entries (d2:gxxx)